# Separate Selection and Ctrl Z

Tags: mesh, workflow, shortcut

I am following a video tutorial (jeep wrangler). The tutor separates a part of the mesh and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Z</kbd>.

This brings back the selection to the same layer, but it is still a different mesh from the rest.

I can not manage to do the same in Blender 2.8

Any idea why ?

Comment: Whats the result in Blender 2.8?

Comment: it would be better if you linked the tutorial   :/

Comment: @Yash When he separate and then press ctrl+Z he gets the original mesh + the separated one. So when he goes to object mode he can pick either the entire mesh or the new separated layer. When I do that I get an undo: I get back my separated mesh to the original and basically the mesh is the same as before. I managed to do it by duplicating the mesh and just erase the parts I did not want from the duplicated one.

Comment: @moonboots Unfortunately the video is not online. It is a paid one.

Comment: Perhaps share some screenshots?

Comment: @moonboots Hi, I am not sure if you would appreciate anything from a screenshot of him pressing P ...I am thinking how to document in order you to help me. I need help, but not sure how to show in a jpeg what is happening....I will try!

Comment: I don't know what he did but if you want to duplicate a part of a mesh, select it, press shift D, then P to separate.

Comment: I think the tutor confused you! Also can't guess what would be the confusion! If the video is downloadable please download it, cut the duration of where you are confused(because you paid for it and can't share the whole tutorial for free), upload it to a file hosting site like Google drive and link it here so we can better understand it! Also try what @moonboots was trying to say!

Comment: I contacted Chris Plush (the tutor) to ask him if I could upload a video recording of my screen on that specific part. Hope he agrees and I can share this with you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apparently it is related to 2.8 version. I wrote to Chris Plush and he tested it. In 2.79 when Ctrl+z on edit mode works different and you will bring back the separation and keep the original mesh at the same time. Now with 2.8 is not possible. So I proceeded by duplicating as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I came up against this very same problem myself today while using 2.82 and was able to find the a way to replicate the result Chris Plush had, so it's likely this post will come up in a google search in the future :).

Select the vertices hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate them and <kbd>right-click</kbd> to keep them in place.
Press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate.

When you <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *edit mode* you will have the smaller mesh for the front side panel and the side guide mesh will have remained intact.

Comment: Yes I did that too :) I think that is the only way